# How can I add an IPv6 gateway?

Tags: ipv6

For example:

```
ip -6 route show | grep ^default
```

There is no output. So there's no default gateway for IPv6.

also I see some complains from the kernel side of things:

> ```
> dmesg | grep IPv6 
> eth0: no IPv6 routers present
> ```

Also, I see that I only have a link-local address and not a global unicast.

> ```
> ifconfig eth0 |grep "inet6 addr:"
> ```

returns an inet6 addr fe80: blahblah blah Scope:Link

The informations I have from ISP is:

1. my ipv6 ip network range
2. my default ipv6 gateway

The question is how I configure these into Linux.

Comment: In what Linux distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

- Network range: 2001:db8::/56
- GW: 2001:db8::1

To just set it up, this would be enough (as root, using iputils2):

```
ip -6 addr add 2001:db8::2/64 dev eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip -6 route add default via 2001:db8::1
```

To make this permanent, consult your distro's documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did followed your steps. Now I have a new kind of error:

> From dead:beef icmp_seq=15 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

Answer (score 0):

add the route to the gateway :

```
ip -6 route add 2004::3 dev eth0
```